# How can I delete serialized objects in Java?

Tags: java, file, oop, serialization, stream

Why when I implement the method **oos.close()** it works(I mean it deletes the file), else - not?

```
       File newFile = new File("D:\\1.ser");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
            oos.writeObject(new A());
            oos.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(newFile.delete()){
            System.out.println(newFile.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }
```

Comment: `close()` releases the file handle. Documentation is your friend https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#close()

Comment: You delete serialized objects by deleting whatever you stored the bytes in -- a file, a byte array, whatever.

Comment: Seems like you already know the answer: you have to close the output stream. You could do that better using try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create a *resource*, you **must** close it. Failure to do so means various bad things happen: The inability to delete files is just one of them; an app that will eventually just hardcrash because the VM ran out of file handles is another.

To do so, use the try-with-resources construct. So, don't do what you wrote. Instead:

```
File newFile = new File("D:\\1.ser");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {

    oos.writeObject(new A());
}
// oos and fos are neccessarily closed here...
// even if exceptions occurred. That's nice!
// thus.. delete will work here.
```

Comment: It’s not necessary to put the FileOutputStream in a separate statement in try-with-resources if the ObjectOutputStream is also in it;  closing the ObjectOutputStream will close its underlying stream.

Comment: .. unless, of course, the OOS dies during construction. Admittedly that is quite rare, but putting the whole chain in the try block is the better style. You can use `var` to cut down on the noise some. There's a reason this syntax exists.